# SQL how to find non-empty string?

Tags: sql, string, azure-synapse

I have a column of phone numbers, which may contain some empty strings. There is no `NULL` value.

```
SELECT COUNT(CONTACTPHONE2) FROM Auct_ABSENTEEBID
-- ANS 7844
SELECT COUNT(CONTACTPHONE2) FROM Auct_ABSENTEEBID WHERE CONTACTPHONE2 IS NOT NULL
-- ANS 7844

SELECT CONTACTPHONE2 FROM Auct_ABSENTEEBID
(908) 303-****


310-871-****
```

We can see there are empty strings between the phone numbers.

```
SELECT CONTACTPHONE2 FROM Auct_ABSENTEEBID WHERE CONTACTPHONE2 LIKE '%^(?!\s*$).*%'
SELECT COUNT(CONTACTPHONE2) FROM Auct_ABSENTEEBID WHERE CONTACTPHONE2 LIKE '%^(?!\s*$).*%'
--ANS 0
```

I used the regex `^(?!\s*$).+"`, but it return nothing and `COUNT` returns 0.

I don't know what cause the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why use a regex at all? Just do a comparison to the empty string '', like:

WHERE NOT CONTACTPHONE2 = ''

That would undoubtedly perform better and it certainly is a bit simpler and more likely to 'just work'.

Comment: True. I made simple things complicated. But why doesn't regex work.